# Problem with rotated pages (pdflscape package) and double-sided printing

Tags: double-sided, printing, landscape, pdflscape

I am using the `pdflscape` package to rotate pages with wide tables on them.  This works fine, but there is a problem when I print the document in duplex mode. 
Its a double-sided document (left and right pages, using the `twoside` option from the `scrbook` document class).

The right pages print correctly,
but the left pages (only those set in landscape mode) are printed upside down. How can I fix this?

Comment: For the posterity:apparently this is a system-specific issue. I have the same problem when using evince as pdf viewer (ubuntu 18.04). But using acrobat reader under windows 10, the pages are printed in the correct orientation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No example supplied, so this is untested, but if you replace occurrences of 90 in a local copy of lscape.sty with

```
\ifodd\c@page\else-\fi 90
```

It might do something useful.

**UPDATE** In comments it seems that this works:

```
\def\myrotate{\ifodd\c@page\else-\fi 90}
\g@addto@macro{\landscape}{\PLS@Rotate{\myrotate}}
```

You might need to switch to

```
  \def\myrotate{90}
```

locally in some environments, depending on needs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with my own printer, maybe it's a configuration issue at the print shop. (I've considered closing the question, but I'll leave it open for the moment in case somebody else runs into the same problem.)

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error message, `Extra \else.`, when I try to compile with `pdflatex`. The modified line is `\g@addto@macro{\landscape}{\PLS@Rotate{\ifodd\c@page\else-\fi 90}}`

Comment: pls@rotate calls `\PLS@CheckAngle` which does `\ifx\\#1\\ ` to check if `#1` is empty. You really don't want `#1` to start with an if in that case. Define a macro `def\myrotate{\ifodd\c@page\else-\fi 90}` and then `\PLS@Rotate{\myrotate}` (still untested)

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. Unfortunately, it seems not to be compatible with `longtable`s. (In long automatically "pagebroken" tables all pages are turned the other way round now.)

Comment: No. longtable and lscape really don't know anything about each other, longtable just dumps its rows on to the main vertical list and lscape rotates whatever is there from tables or normal text without knowing which is which.

Comment: You need to find out why the pages were rotating in the first place. I half suspect that it is your pdf viewer (or printer) trying to automatically detect the orientation and adding automatic rotation. The table layout may confuse it so it doesn't do that, so the correction-to-the-correction is not needed in that case. In any case now you have `\myrotate` you can switch its definition between having the `\ifodd` test or not each time you start a lscape environment.

Comment: That's not very convenient, but as the problem seems to be related to specific printer problems, it should do. Thanks!

Comment: (Maybe you could modify the code in your answer to `\def\myrotate{\ifodd\c@page\else-\fi 90}` + `\g@addto@macro{\landscape}{\PLS@Rotate{\myrotate}}` or similar.)

Answer (score 2):

if it's single page figures you're after, and you're happy with floats, try the rotating package.

rotating goes to some lengths to get rotation consistent.