# How to rotate the pdf page with a sidewaystable/figure without using pdflscape?

Tags: rotating, pdflscape, sidewaysfigure

I have a `sidewaysfigure`, however I'd like to rotate the `pdf` page containing this table, avoiding the use of `pdflscape` package. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
%
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
I'd like to rotate this page
\caption{An example}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I discovered while trying to place the figure... there are problems with the above answer and it needs some expansion. I gave a try and got a good result but did not really used sideways figure... Just used tikz package and placed everything in a rotated minipage as a hack. I also had to get rid of the pagenumber.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. `sidewaysfigure/table` will rotate the page where the figure will be placed, while the answers in the other thread create a rotated page where to place the content. Moreover, `sideways` will rotate differently `twoside` documents; the other thread does not cover it. To fully answer this, you need to combine [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45279/26355) to patch the rotation, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305730/26355) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180963/26355) to avoid interrupting the text (with `afterpage`).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par

\pagebreak


\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rotate=90] at (0,0) {\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
                   \begin{center}
                   I'd like to rotate this page
                   \end{center}
                   \blindtext

                   \centering
                   \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                      \captionof{figure}{Test caption}
                \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagebreak

\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}
\Blindtext


\end{document}
```

From the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40692/120578

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  text

  \pagebreak[4]
  \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
  text
  \pagebreak

  \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}
  text
\end{document}
```

I didn't want to change the original answer, so I wrote this here as an answer to a duplicate question (I am going to flag it but I will reffer to it in the comments in the original answer).

Comment: It didn't work in my example

Comment: Did you tried my edit?

Comment: I tryed, however I didn't like the result, because the text in the last page was centered

Comment: Sorry for that... my mistake ... fixed (just remove the `\centering` after `\thispagestyle`)