# How do I set the Rotate attribute for a landscape page of a pdf produced by xelatex?

Tags: landscape, adjustbox, pdflscape

I've adopted [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57531/42348) to rotate a table and its caption. I do *not* want to rotate the header, the footer, the section title not the paragraph on the same page.

Now I want to change the Rotate attribute as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40692/42348) so that the page is turned to landscape by the viewer application. I know the same question has been asked in [this duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392792/42348), but I need to use xelatex and the compiler complains about pdfpageattr to be an undefined control sequence.

Am I right to assume that pdflscape has no option to prevent changes to the layout in the landscape environment?

**mwe:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{%
  ,adjustbox%
  ,tabularx%
  ,ragged2e%
  ,blindtext%
  ,placeins%
  % ,pdflscape% <- I only want the pdf viewer to rotate the page
}
\begin{document}

\section{Portrait page}

\Blindtext[3][1]
\pagebreak[4]
% \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
% --> Undefined control sequence. <--

% I can't use pdflscape's landscape environment as it changes the layout.

\section{Landscape page}

This running text should be ``portrait''--readable.

% (leave 10ex room for the title and the paragraph.)
\begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth-10ex,%
      addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{%
          \caption{%
            Here is a caption of the table which is so long that 
            it has to be wrapped over multiple lines, but should 
            not exceed the width (height after the rotation) of the table.
          }%
    \end{minipage}},rotate=90,center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|r|XXXXX|}
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large\slshape rotated table}}\\
      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\\hline
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\
    a & b & c & d & e & f \\\hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
\pagebreak[4]
% \global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 0}
\Blindtext[2][1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xetex doesn't know \pdfpageattr, you need to use a \special with it

```
  \special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate #1>>}%
```

(#1 is the angle).

You can use e.g. this internal commands of pdflscape to get the right effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
blblb

\makeatletter\PLS@AddRotate{90}\makeatletter

\newpage

\makeatletter\PLS@RemoveRotate\makeatother
blblb

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I knew about \special and I looked through the source but I could not figure it out.

Comment: The documentation about parameters for `\special` in this case is the manual of the [`dvipdfm` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/dviware/dvipdfm/dvipdfm.pdf).