# Rotate all pages of the output PDF by 90 degrees

Tags: xetex, pdf, koma-script, rotating, page

How do I get XeLaTeX to output all pages of the PDF by 90 degrees? The content should be rotated, too. This is less of a typesetting, and more of a PDF output question. I am using KOMA-Script with XeLaTeX.

To add some detail to the question, consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
not rotated
\begin{landscape}
rotated
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The typesetting is just how I want it. However, *only the landscaped page* is rotated. If I change `pdflscape` to `lscape`, then *no page* is rotated. How do get to rotate *all pages* in the output?

I am aware that I could use a tool like `qpdf` afterwards, but I would like to do it directly with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing the question out, I have found a solution by looking at the [source of `pdflscape`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdflscape/pdflscape.pdf), based on this [answer about setting the rotation attribute with XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459983/85197) and the manual of the [`dvipdfm` driver](http://mirrors.ctan.org/dviware/dvipdfm/dvipdfm.pdf) (however I am not sure if this is the correct documentation for `\special` in XeLaTeX):

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lscape}
\special{pdf: put @pages << /Rotate 90 >>}

\begin{document}
not rotated
\begin{landscape}
rotated
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The `lscape` package will not rotate any PDF pages, and the `\special` command rotates all of them.